# How to merge two repositories?

Tags: c#

How to merge two git repositories into one?
 I have got a parent folder say 'P' and two subfolders 'A' which has 5 commits and 'B' which has 5 commits.
 I want the repos in A and B to disappear and combine as one with 10 commits,this new repository must be placed in the parent directory 'P'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you merge two Git repositories?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories)

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is to merge two repositories are as follows

Create a new empty repository New.
Make an initial commit because we need one before we do a merge.
Add a remote to old repository old A.
Merge old A/master to New/master.
Make a sub directory old A.
Move all files into sub directory old A.
Commit all of the file moves.
Repeat 3-6 for old B.